# wrap long strings sublimetext python

Tags: python, sublimetext

Is there some magical way to have SublimeText handle a line like this automatically for me?

```
print('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dapibus mauris urna, in semper dolor semper eget. Proin condimentum est sed est elementum, eu pulvinar eros malesuada. Quisque malesuada sapien et quam convallis, et sodales risus blandit. Vestibulum auctor justo eu libero pellentesque tempor. Quisque faucibus augue eu fermentum auctor.')
```

I'm honestly indifferent of it coming out like this:

```
print('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dapibus'
      'mauris urna, in semper dolor semper eget. Proin condimentum est sed est'
      'elementum, eu pulvinar eros malesuada. Quisque malesuada sapien et quam'
      'convallis, et sodales risus blandit. Vestibulum auctor justo eu libero'
      'pellentesque tempor. Quisque faucibus augue eu fermentum auctor.')
```

or like this:

```
print(
    'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent dapibus'
    'mauris urna, in semper dolor semper eget. Proin condimentum est sed est'
    'elementum, eu pulvinar eros malesuada. Quisque malesuada sapien et quam'
    'convallis, et sodales risus blandit. Vestibulum auctor justo eu libero'
    'pellentesque tempor. Quisque faucibus augue eu fermentum auctor.'
)
```

or any other 'pythonic' way to handle a long string. Basically I want to write a long string, highlight it, and hit a button and find it is magically formatted some acceptable way. I would also really like to have some way to edit this string once it's already made without doing the work all over again.

Currently what I do is write this string, use Wrap->Wrap at X characters, then go through manually and add quotes to the start and end of each line and also adjust the indenting if necessary. If I want to edit, I have to then go and remove the starting and ending quotes in each line, concatenate it to one line, fix it, then do it all over again. It's awful.

Comment: Something like this: https://github.com/ehuss/Sublime-Wrap-Plus ?

Comment: Something like this, yes. But unless I'm doing something wrong, which I very certainly could be, this plugin doesn't help anymore than the built in Wrap at X function does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using triple quotes doesn't work for all situations you might quote text, but I reasoned out a way to handle this slightly better than manual.

1. Use SublimeWrapPlus linked above to keep SublimeText from confusing one line of code with the one below it and only wrapping highlighted lines.
2. Alt Q wraps highlighted lines, Ctrl J joins them.
3. Use multi-line select with your middle mouse button or shift+rbutton to draw a vertical line along the first character of your code block.
4. Use R/L arrow to get to the first character, then hitting ' or " will add quotes to every line you clicked.
5. Now hit end or the arrow keys to goto the end of the line and hit ' or " again.

To undo this for editing you just remove the quotes with multi-line select again and then join the lines.

This is hardly an ideal solution but much better than what I was doing before.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to make multiple single-quoted lines like in your question, but you need to join them in the print statement:

```
print('long line 1' + \
      'long line 2' + \
      ...
      )
```

and it'd be a huge amount of work to undo that every time you wanted to edit the strings. So, why not just use a triple-quoted string?

```
print("""Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent
dapibus mauris urna, in semper dolor semper eget. Proin condimentum est sed
est elementum, eu pulvinar eros malesuada. Quisque malesuada sapien et quam
convallis, et sodales risus blandit. Vestibulum auctor justo eu libero
pellentesque tempor. Quisque faucibus augue eu fermentum auctor.""")
```

First, enter your mega-text on one line. Then, select it (I use the [Expand Selection to Quotes](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Expand%20Selection%20to%20Quotes) plugin and just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>) and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to wrap. If you need to edit the string, select all the text and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join the lines back into one. When you're done editing, you can rewrap.

In my preferences I have

```
"word_wrap": "true",
"wrap_width": 0
```

so that even a single long string will automatically wrap like so:

[image: wordwrap]

Good luck!

Comment: Your assertion that you need to join strings in the print statement with a plus sign is simple untrue. From the docs on `String literal concatenation` https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation . What is needed is a way to simply terminate the string at column 80 with a quote, and then start the string again on the next line.

Comment: "Why not use a triple quoted string?" Because then there will be literal line breaks everywhere.